# R: assignment using values from several rows

Tags: r, variable-assignment, dplyr

Say I have measured some value (`value`encoded as H,L or I) in five individuals (`id`) at two time points (`time`). Sometimes NAs may occur in `value`:

```
require(stringr)
require(dplyr)    
set.seed(8)

df1 <- data.frame(
  time=rep(c(1,2), 5),
  id=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),2),
  value=sample(c("H","L","I", NA), replace=T, 10))
```

How can I make a factor variable (preferable using `dplyr::mutate()`) that indicates for each `id`the transition of `value` from time 1 to time 2 (e.g: like "HL" if H at time 1 and L at time 2).

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(time)
```

Gives:

```
time id value
1     1  a     L
2     2  a     I
3     1  b     L
4     2  b     H
5     1  c    NA
6     2  c    NA
7     1  d    NA
8     2  d     I
9     1  e     L
10    2  e     I
```

And I would need a fourth column indicating time transition, like (made-up):

```
   time id value transition
1     1  a     L         L-I
2     2  a     I         L-I
3     1  b     L         L-H
4     2  b     H         L-H
5     1  c    NA         NA-NA
6     2  c    NA         NA-NA
7     1  d    NA         NA-I
8     2  d     I         NA-I
9     1  e     L         L-I
10    2  e     I         L-I
```

Something like (if only the `str_c()` command could do it):

```
df1 <- 
  df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(transition=str_c(value, sep="-"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(transition = paste0(value[1],"-",value[2]))
```

Comment: Or `paste(value, collapse='-'))` (+1)

Comment: Ah so simple (if you knew it). Perfect - +1.

Comment: I guess akrun's is more general if you have different numbers of time observations for the ids (which DMC couldnt know since I didnt mention that in my question) ?

Comment: In the end, it was all about the group_by()